# How do I find all the even numbers in a vector WITHOUT using mod, loops, or predefined functions?

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R, and I came across a problem asking for a program that calculates the number of even numbers in a vector without using loops, %%, or any predefined R functions. The only ones I can use are apply(), length(), and sum(). I have been trying to use if statements, but nothing seems to be working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: I've tried using recursive if statements, but I am using the mod function. I have not yet found a way around that, but even this does not print anything when I try it.

if(v[i]%%2==0){
    t<-t+1
    i<-i+1
    even(v)
  }

Comment: are you allowed to use `*` , `/`?

Comment: You can try as: `sum(v==as.integer(v/2)*2)` where `v` is vector

Comment: When using that, how can I go through each member of the vector? Or will it do that by default?

Comment: it will do by default. The condition is checked against each item in vector. I have added an answer with example vector. You can run it to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try comparing `dividing by 2` and then `multiplying by 2`.

```
v <- 1:20

sum(v==as.integer(v/2)*2)
#[1] 10

#Using length
length(v[v==as.integer(v/2)*2])
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out. It's always the simplest solutions that I miss.